# Handle missing XML-elements

Tags: c#, xml

In my C# project, I am getting XML-files from clients and I need to turn the data from some of the elements into a flat datatable. Problem is, some of the files are (validly) missing elements (because they dont contain any data).

I have solved the problem very manually by checking for the existence of elements, like so:

```
if(node.Childnodes(0).Childnodes(1).Count > 0)
Mystring = node.Childnodes(0).Childnodes(1).Childnodes(0).InnerText;
else
MyString = string.Empty;
```

This works, but if there are additional elements that may be missing in the future, the code would be very complex. Does anyone know of a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: Using Xml Linq works very well in this situation as long a you cast object and not use 'Value'.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try casting to a custom object.